# Perfect Secrecy and Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: information-theory

Perfect Secrecy can be defined by

$I(M;Z^n) = D(P_{MZ^n}||P_MP_{Z^n}) = 0$

there the true joint distribution $P_{MZ^n}$ is compared to the product distributions $P_M P_{Z^n}$.

The system can be viewed as follows:

```
M -> Enc E -> X^n -> P_{yz|x} -> Y^n -> Dec -> ^M
                              -> Z^n -> Eve -> ?
```

I'm struggeling with the interpretation of the Kullback-Leibler divergence. Can someone give me some intuitive explanation?

Comment: What is $D(P_{MZ^n}||P_MP_{Z^n})$?

Comment: I thought it is the Kullback-Leibler divergence? So the "distance" between the probability-distributions.

Comment: Yes.  Okay, this looks to be a nice summary https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Hershey3/publication/4249249_Approximating_the_Kullback_Leibler_Divergence_Between_Gaussian_Mixture_Models/links/56b46b9d08ae61c480592ca9/Approximating-the-Kullback-Leibler-Divergence-Between-Gaussian-Mixture-Models.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I think I have now some explanation. $P_{MZ^n}$ should be $P_M P_{Z^n}$, meaning that both are statistical independent.

Answer (score 0):

The KL-Divergence is defined as

$$
   D(p_x || q_x) = \sum _x p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$

and the mutual information is defined as

$$
   I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y) = \sum_x \sum_y p(x,y) \log \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}
$$

from the above it's clear that $I(X;Y) = D(p_{xy} || p_xp_y )$

Comment: Okay, thanks. :) But why should I define it like that? I'm searching for some visualization or intuitive explanation.

Comment: This only holds for statistical independence?